# Shared Internet apply /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, internet-sharing, hosts

How do I make those who connect to me via a shared internet connection use my /etc/hosts file? I was thinking something along the lines of creating a DNS server, but I was hoping maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: Why dio you want to do this - a bit more info will help us to think what the solution is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install a DNS server. If you need a DNS server that automatically synthesizes answers from the contents of `/etc/hosts`, use [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Gas Mask](http://code.google.com/p/gmask/) that let you share some hosts through some file on the network, your users would have to install it and configure it to the right file.